# Using assembler inside C from converted c file

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly, embedded

im new to using asm into C code ,so sorry if my question is too dumb.
The thing is I wrote a program in C  which codes a text file based on a code rule file.But im trying to make some methods in asm.So I made the compiler(Visual compiler) to make a asm file of my code.The thing is when I see the asm code for one method there are things like this. And if I try to paste it over my method add, inside the __asm{} ,i get errors even though is the same asm output.
How can I put this asm code inside my function?
Thanks...

```
_movement$ = -20                                        ; size = 4
_leftBits$ = -16                                        ; size = 4
_hexa$ = -12                                            ; size = 4
_actualByte$ = -8                                 ; size = 4
_character$ = -2                                        ; size = 1
_temp$ = -1                                   ; size = 1
_data$ = 8                                          ; size = 4
_code$ = 12                                   ; size = 1
_longg$ = 16                                            ; size = 4
_positionBit$ = 20                                  ; size = 4
add PROC
        push     ebp
        mov      ebp, esp
        sub      esp, 20              ; 00000014H
        mov      eax, DWORD PTR _positionBit$[ebp]
        cdq
        and      edx, 7
        add      eax, edx
        sar      eax, 3
        mov      DWORD PTR _actualByte$[ebp], eax
        mov      eax, DWORD PTR _positionBit$[ebp]
        and      eax, -2147483641 ; 80000007H
        jns      SHORT $LN4@add
        dec      eax
        or       eax, -8                    ; fffffff8H
        inc      eax
$LN4@add:
        mov      DWORD PTR _leftBits$[ebp], eax
        mov      ecx, DWORD PTR _data$[ebp]
        add      ecx, DWORD PTR _actualByte$[ebp]
        mov      dl, BYTE PTR [ecx]
        mov      BYTE PTR _character$[ebp], dl
        mov      DWORD PTR _hexa$[ebp], 255 ; 000000ffH
        mov      eax, 8
        sub      eax, DWORD PTR _longg$[ebp]
        mov      DWORD PTR _movement$[ebp], eax
        mov      edx, DWORD PTR _hexa$[ebp]
        mov      ecx, DWORD PTR _movement$[ebp]
        sar      edx, cl
        mov      DWORD PTR _hexa$[ebp], edx
        movzx    eax, BYTE PTR _code$[ebp]
        and      eax, DWORD PTR _hexa$[ebp]
        mov      BYTE PTR _code$[ebp], al
        mov      cl, BYTE PTR _code$[ebp]
        mov      BYTE PTR _temp$[ebp], cl
        mov      edx, 8
        sub      edx, DWORD PTR _longg$[ebp]
        add      edx, 1
        cmp      DWORD PTR _leftBits$[ebp], edx
        jge      SHORT $LN1@add
        mov      ecx, 8
        sub      ecx, DWORD PTR _leftBits$[ebp]
        mov      eax, 255   ; 000000ffH
        shl      eax, cl
        mov      ecx, DWORD PTR _data$[ebp]
        add      ecx, DWORD PTR _actualByte$[ebp]
        movzx    edx, BYTE PTR [ecx]
        and      edx, eax
        mov      eax, DWORD PTR _data$[ebp]
        add      eax, DWORD PTR _actualByte$[ebp]
        mov      BYTE PTR [eax], dl
        movzx    edx, BYTE PTR _temp$[ebp]
        mov      ecx, 8
        sub      ecx, DWORD PTR _longg$[ebp]
        sub      ecx, DWORD PTR _leftBits$[ebp]
        shl      edx, cl
        mov      eax, DWORD PTR _data$[ebp]
        add      eax, DWORD PTR _actualByte$[ebp]
        movzx    ecx, BYTE PTR [eax]
        or       ecx, edx
        mov      edx, DWORD PTR _data$[ebp]
        add      edx, DWORD PTR _actualByte$[ebp]
        mov      BYTE PTR [edx], cl
$LN1@add:
        mov      esp, ebp
        pop      ebp
        ret      0
add ENDP
```

this is the error log when trying to compile.

```
simple.c(185): error C2059: syntax error: '__asm'
simple.c(201): error C2059: syntax error: 'bad suffix on number'
simple.c(209): error C2059: syntax error: 'bad suffix on number'
simple.c(210): error C2018: unknown character '0x40'
simple.c(214): error C2018: unknown character '0x40'
simple.c(220): error C2059: syntax error: 'bad suffix on number'
simple.c(237): error C2018: unknown character '0x40'
simple.c(240): error C2059: syntax error: 'bad suffix on number'
simple.c(261): error C2018: unknown character '0x40'
```

Comment: “i get errors” is a completely useless statement as we don't know what those errors are.  If you receive an error message, always tell us exactly what error you receive and show us the corresponding source code.  Otherwise, it's very hard to help you.

Comment: In addition to what fuz said, let me also ask what you are trying to accomplish here.  If the goal is to try to make your code run faster, that's likely to be a lot harder than you expect.  Modern C compilers can use a huge number of tricks and optimizations learned over decades of writing code.  If the goal is to teach yourself assembler, you have picked the absolute most difficult way to do it.  If writing code this way is some type of homework project, your teacher is an idiot.

Comment: Sorry for not addressing the errors properly,i have edited the question.David  its  a homework proyect about C , but im trying to see what happens when doing some functions on ASM,making the software faster is not my goal, as you said, compiler often makes this optimizations very good.The thing is i cant put the output asm code inside my function in C because it breaks during compilation.

Comment: You can't or at least shouldn't put that entire code inside inline asm.  It makes a stack frame and looks for args on the stack, rather than loading inputs from named C variables.

You could port it to inline asm and put it inside `__asm { ... }` if you want (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93.aspx for docs on the syntax).

I guess you already figured that out for the followup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665923/inline-assembly-doesnt-work-in-c-in-visual-32bits.

Comment: Sequences like `mov      BYTE PTR _code$[ebp], al  /   mov      cl, BYTE PTR _code$[ebp]`, which stores and reloads a variable, shows that this is unoptimized (debug mode) code that you are not going to learn anything from (except how *not* to code assembly).

Answer (score 0):

I know very little about Assembly (what I do know about it comes from C/Linux) so I'll try to suggest something that helps.

Does your function need any parameters passed to it? Does it need to return something to its caller? You could write a short C source file, that only defines a little function like this.

```
void butts(void) {
    printf("butts\n");
}
```

And then convert that single file to assembly the way you did. Name it what you want, but remember it. This should give you an assembler source file with the function name `butts`. Then, you could put the code you posted in your question, into that assembly file. Make sure it can be called with the name you set. I don't think the `__asm{}` will work the way you want it to.

Then, I believe, you could compile that assembly file as an object, and link it with the C-sourced compiled objects, so you could compile the whole thing together. Make sure you define whatever this function is in a C (or header) file, without writing the body of the function. Use the prototype like this:

```
void butts(void);
```

Sorry if this is hogwash or doesn't help at all. Just brainstorming and something like this might work for you.

Comment: Thanks, it did helped me to see  a more clear function in asm , but im still haviong some trouble :)